# Remove property from json event Splunk

Tags: json, events, filter, splunk

I have events JSON events in splunk, but one of the key pair/property I would like to remove.

E.g.:

From below JSON I want to remove "country": "Algeria", from every event which will come. It is possible? I have tried something like this in my props.conf, but no success.

```
[k8s]
INDEXED_EXTRACTIONS=JSON
TRUNCATE = 200000
SEDCMD-remove=/"country": ".*/g
```

```
       {
            "random": 23,
            "random float": 28.173,
            "bool": false,
            "date": "1990-08-31",
            "regEx": "helloooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo world",
            "enum": "generator",
            "firstname": "Latisha",
            "lastname": "Alexandr",
            "city": "Tiraspol",
            "country": "Algeria",
            "countryCode": "MC",
            "email uses current data": "Latisha.Alexandr@gmail.com",
            "email from expression": "Latisha.Alexandr@yopmail.com",
            "array": [
                "Dyann",
                "Christal",
                "Renie",
                "Tilly",
                "Margette"
            ],
            "array of objects": [
                {
                    "index": 0,
                    "index start at 5": 5
                },
                {
                    "index": 1,
                    "index start at 5": 6
                },
                {
                    "index": 2,
                    "index start at 5": 7
                }
            ],
            "Raquela": {
                "age": 50
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, but the `SEDCMD` is incorrect.  Try this in your props.conf

```
SEDCMD-noAlgeria = s/"country": "Algeria",//
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! I dont want any country or whole this KV. I will plaz with that, but now I know that it works. Thanks

Comment: @Jakub `=/search/` matches the search string but it doesn't do anything with the match but `=/search/replace/` replaces the matched search string with the replacement so `=s/"country": "Algeria",//` replaces `"country": "Algeria",` with nothing.  If you want to replace every line containing country with nothing try `=s/"country": "[^"]*",//` or `=s/"country": .*//`